# How to invoke a GUI Class from external apk in android

Tags: android, reflection

I have loaded a external apk through DexClassLoader.
in a method will be invoked has a GUI load from .xml layout.
But i can not view this GUI (from external apk) through invoke method !!

In conclusion, I want to load a GUI from an external APK file through invoke method.
Please help me !!
p/s: sorry about my english!

```
final File _optimizedDexOutputPath = getDir("outdex", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String _className;
    String _methodToInvoke;
    String _apkfilePath;


    HashMap<String, String> hmData;

    //Prepare
    hmData = preWorkflow();
    _className = hmData.get("className");
    _apkfilePath = hmData.get("apkfilePath");
    _methodToInvoke = hmData.get("methodToInvoke");


    DexClassLoader dLoader = new DexClassLoader(_apkfilePath,
            _optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),
            null, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent());
    try {
        Class<?> loadedClass = dLoader.loadClass(_className);
        Object obj = (Object) loadedClass.newInstance();

        Method m = loadedClass.getDeclaredMethod(_methodToInvoke);
        m.invoke(obj);

    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
       e.getCause().printStackTrace();
    }  catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The code that are you are executing will execute under one of your `Context`s, and therefore it will not have access to the resources of the other APK. Nor will it have the permissions of the other APK, access to the files of the other app, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you don't have a unit 'GUI'. You are probably talking about an `Activity`. If you want to launch an `Activity` of another package there is no need for reflection. Simply send an `Intent`. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html

Comment: Yes, but the activity that i want to launch not installed in my device; it's attached in assets folder !!

Comment: You can't launch an activity which is not registered in any manifest. Reflection won't help here. The only solution which comes to my mind would be xposed, but that would require really deep system hacking.